# Android ToolBar with 3 Fragments

Tags: android

I have spent a lot of time searching about the use of the new ToolBar.
I'm trying to develop an app with 1 activity and 3 fragments. The activity has a layout with the toolbar and a container where the fragments will be fit.
The question is: is possible to define the toolbar once in the activity and share it with the 3 fragments or each fragment have to define its own toolbar inside the respective layout?

I'm using appcompat and the activity extends ActionBarActivity.

I have medium skill in Android and appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment is like a pluggable sub-Activity, and each instance of Fragment must be managed by an Activity, though, each Fragment has its own life-cycle callbacks, but its life-cycle is directly affected and determined by the life-cycle of its host Activity. You can plug as many Fragments into an Activity as you like by using a horizontal-swiping ViewGroup such as the `ViewPager` , example Facebook app, it has 4 Fragments and they are wrapped in a `ViewPager` ViewGroup. In one word, each Fragment that you added to a common Activity will have the same UI like ActionBar or Toolbar or whatever. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I understood your explanation about the life-cycle and callbacks. However, i am not using a ViewGroup but a Navigation Drawer to call each Fragment, I think it will work as well. And one more question: the toolbar listeners will stay on the Activity and can hear all the events normally, right?

Comment: A Navigation Drawer is created by the use of the `DrawerLayout` widget which is a child of `ViewGroup`. A Toolbar is a new API added for android version 21 and up, and it is pretty much like the Action Bar (If you are familiar with the Action Bar), and in fact, you can make the Toolbar behave like the Action Bar by calling the method `Activity.setActionBar()`, but Toolbar offers more features than a traditional Action Bar does. I think you should get yourself familiar with the Action Bar, action menu and the like, it would greatly help understand the Toolbar better...

Comment: ...Google provided an excellent tutorial on Action Bar I strongly recommend you reading it top to bottom. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)...To anwser your question above, " the toolbar listeners will stay on the Activity and can hear all the events normally, right?" as long as your listener is not destroyed, then yes, it will listen to any events you register to it.

Comment: I forgot one thing, the Toolbar API also has a support version to be used with devices running android version 2.2 (or 2.3 cant remember exactly) Eclair and up.

Comment: You gave me a great explanation. I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation yet. Thank you very much.

Comment: I voted up your question so you could get some points, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help. Great question though